# How to pass Correct Web Service URL in Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have an asp.net Web service which contains a method that i have to call through Ajax jquery .Now i have published and deployed this web service into IIS and through localhost i am able to access this webservice and web method.

Here is the URL of the WebMethod on Local host..

```
http://localhost/app/DateWebService.asmx/GetData
```

Now as per my requirement i need to call this WebMethod `GetData` from the jquery Ajax call on button Click Event .Now as soon as i click on the button i can see the alert message that is in success method of the ajax but can not see the response ..
For response i am getting following error in the console

```
TypeError: msg is null
$("#output").text(msg.d);
```

Here is my Ajax Call code..

```
        $("#Button1").click(function () {

            var Name = "asdfg";
            var Contact = "79749497979";
            var Email = "hr@gmail.com";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/app/DateWebService.asmx/GetData",
                data: '{"Name":"' + Name + '","Contact":"' + Contact + '","Email":"' + Email + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {

                    $("#output").text(msg.d);
                }
            });
        });
```

Please help me to get over this error ..Thanks in advance..

and this is my WebMethod Code..

```
  [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetData(string Name, string Contact, string Email)
{
    return Name + Contact + Email;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the success function? You should be able to stop the execution and see exactly what "msg" is. Also, I would post the web service code so we can see what is getting returned.

Comment: @macoms01 I posted the WebMethod Code too ..Please have a look..

Comment: @macoms01 Any suggestion on the same..

Comment: @macoms01 Also i checked Console of browser and got this error `2
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/app/DateWebService.asmx/GetData. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error, but to clarify, your javascript code executes the success function of the ajax call, correct? It then errors out when trying to display "msg.d"?

Comment: @macoms01 I got it running ..Please see my answer below ..Thanks fo r your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Solution .Issue was with the Permission . I Added one line in my Client side code ..i.e

```
crossDomain: true,
```

and added these two lines in `Web.config` file of my Web service..

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

Like this

```
<system.webServer>

<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="DateWebService.asmx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

and I got it up..

Comment: You might have a "false solution" to your issue. If you're testing locally (`localhost`), check if your way of debugging includes a port (e.g. localhost:1234). [CORS is for `cross-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) requests. It may not be evident, but that **also** includes the [port number](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) - re: `http://localhost` is **not** the same as `http://localhost:1234`

Answer (score 0):

```
data: JSON.stringify('{"Name":"' + Name + '","Contact":"' + Contact + '","Email":"' + Email + '"}'),
```

Comment: Sorry to tell you but no help with this ..I am getting `2
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/app/DateWebService.asmx/GetData. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Comment: Any suggestion on the same?

Comment: can you navigate to your asmx and test the function? Also, you are refering to http://localhost/app/DateWebService.asmx/GetData where in your project your JS file located?

Comment: I got the solution which i added as answer too.Thanks for your help